# Problem with multiple asp.net application instances

Tags: asp.net, instance

I have an asp.net application that uses the file (something like hand-made DB). It opens the file in non-shared mode. That's why only a single instance of site can use it.

But the problems begin when I'm updating the site on server (via app_offline.htm trick)

Sometimes the updated instance of AppDomain starts before the old application has stopped.
I have 2 instances of AppDomain working at the same time.

Is there any standard way to prevent it?

**PS:** I know about "Overlapped recycle" setting in Application Pool, but this is another thing. It is for multiple application pools working at the same time, but I have single application pool with several instances of the same application.

Comment: I don't know about standard way, but I think the big non-standard thing here is single access 'hand-made DB'...

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of storage I use, the problem is with non-shared access.
"Overlapped recycle" setting in Application Pool was designed for these reasons too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://hyperthink.net/blog/recycling-appdomains-not-cans/) perfectly explains the situation.

To solve my problem I need to use

> HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject()

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution

```
  internal class AppInstanceSyncronizer
    {
    bool m_HasHandle;
    EventWaitHandle m_Event;

    const int START_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 60 * 1000;

    const string GLOBAL_EVENT_NAME="{D22555A0-BF47-41fd-AFC9-D83B4EADF75C}";

    internal bool OnAppStart()
      {
      bool createdNew;
      m_Event = new EventWaitHandle(false,EventResetMode.AutoReset,GLOBAL_EVENT_NAME,out createdNew);
      if(createdNew) { m_Event.Set(); }
      //--- first time created event
      m_HasHandle = m_Event.WaitOne(START_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
      return m_HasHandle;
      }

    internal void OnAppEnd()
      {
      //--- Release the event
      if(m_HasHandle)
        m_Event.Set();
      }
```

Just call `OnAppStart` and `OnAppEnd` where your application starts and stops